# What does 'f' suffix mean in x86 assembly code integer constant

Tags: assembly, x86

For example this line: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/boot/header.S#L297. I think b means binary number, o mean octal number, h means hex number. But what does f mean? In most languages it means floating number but doesn't seem to make sense here.

Answer (score 5):

That's a reference to a local label.  A label comprising just a single digit is called a *local label.*  The expression `1f` refers to the next (forward) label named `1` whereas `1b` refers to the previous (backward) label named `1`.